# Parsing data from text file and createing an excel spreadsheet

Tags: java, excel, java.util.scanner, java-io, jxl

I'm trying to take specific data from a .txt file and fill an excel spreadsheet in a specific way. My code went from elegant with lots of OOP principles to the code below, brute force and gross. I'm testing as I go (just extesion right now) and it only adds the first number in the spreadsheet.

Here is what the report is suppose to look like

http://imgur.com/7rswqSb

here is the raw data from the text file im sorting through

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EK29K.jpg

The raw data isn't consistent(wishing it was it would make it easier)
ex: some extension numbers have multiple vector/step #'s

```
 import java.io.*;
 import java.util.Scanner;
 import java.util.Date;
 import jxl.*;
 import jxl.write.*; 
 import jxl.write.biff.RowsExceededException;

 public class ReadFromFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, RowsExceededException, WriteException
    {

        // Location of file to read
        File raw = new File("reports1.txt");
        //File rawNoQ = new File("rawNoQ.txt");

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(raw);

        WritableWorkbook workbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File("output.xls")); 
        WritableSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("First Sheet", 0);



        int extensionNum = 0;
        int vectorNum = 0;
        int stepNum = 0;
        int vdnNum = 0;
        boolean voaExt = false;

        int rowNum = 0;
        int colNum =0;

        //int tempN = 0;
        //String tempS = "";
        //boolean Anouncment =false;


        while (scanner.hasNextLine())
                {

            extensionNum = 0;
            vectorNum = 0;
            stepNum = 0;
            vdnNum = 0;
            voaExt = false;

            //finds extension number
            if (scanner.findInLine("usa e ") != null)
            {
                extensionNum = scanner.nextInt();

                System.out.println(extensionNum + "   <-----  Extension Number");


                ExtWrite(workbook,sheet,colNum,rowNum,Integer.toString(extensionNum));
                rowNum++;

            }

            //finds VDN Number
            if (scanner.findInLine("VDN Number") != null)
            {
                scanner.next();
                scanner.useDelimiter("\"");
                scanner.next();

                vdnNum = scanner.nextInt();

                System.out.println(vdnNum + "   <-----  VDN Number");
                scanner.reset();

                voaExt = true;
            }

            //finds vector number
            if (scanner.findInLine("Vector Number") != null)
            {
                scanner.next();
                scanner.useDelimiter("\"");
                scanner.next();

                vectorNum = scanner.nextInt();
                System.out.println(vectorNum + "   <-----  Vector Number");
                scanner.reset();

                scanner.next();
                scanner.next();
                scanner.useDelimiter("\"");
                scanner.next();

                stepNum = scanner.nextInt();
                System.out.println(stepNum + "   <-----  Step Number");
                scanner.reset();

            }

            scanner.nextLine();

                }   //end of while loop    
        workbook.close();
    }

    public static void ExtWrite(WritableWorkbook workbook, WritableSheet sheet, int colNum, int rowNum, String extension) throws IOException, RowsExceededException, WriteException
    {
        Label label1 = new Label(colNum, rowNum, extension );

        sheet.addCell(label1); 

        workbook.write();   

    }

}
```